Create spring project doesn't show java 8 like java type
I try to create a new Spring starter project( I use only jdk 8) and when I must select java type version java 8 doesn't appear in the list:

I use Sping tool suite 4.16.1 and I modify the jdk in path:

AND The compiler:

My java home:

and my path:

I don't know why java 8 doens't appear in java type when I'm creating the spring project. Anyone can help me?

The only supported Spring Boot versions as of date require Java17 as a minimum. So yes Java 8 deosn't appear here as there is no supported Spring (Boot) version available that runs on that.

From Spring Boot version 3.0 and above, Java 8 is no longer supported. If you wish to use Java 8, you must use Spring Boot version 2.x or earlier. Below is a compatibility list of Spring Boot versions and their supported Java versions:
Spring Boot Version                 Compatible Java Versions
[1.x  spring supports                               6, 7, 8 version of java]
[2.x  spring supports                               8, 9, 10, 11, 17 version of java ]
[3.x  spring supports                               17 and above version of java ]

Spring Boot 1 and Spring Boot 2 aren't supported anymore and thus not selectable in the wizard!

thanx for the information i was just letting him know which version is compatible with which version

When using initializer it will only show supported Spring Boot versions. The current minimum version is 3.2.11 and there is no lower version. Spring Boot 3 requires Java 17 as a minimum requirement to run. Due to this there is no option to select an earlier version of Java to run with as that simply isn't supported.
